# Groovy/Java: Optimize/Refactor If statement

Tags: if-statement, groovy, refactoring

How do I refactor the following if statement that checks if the value exists and assigns it to a new object?

```
Domain myMethod(DomainOld param) {

    Domain domain = new Domain()

    if (param.id) {
        domain.id = param.id
    }

    if (param.name) {
        domain.name = param.name
    }

    if (param.status) {
        domain.status = param.status
    }

    if (param.value) {
        domain.value = param.value
    }

    domain.save()

    return domain
}
```

Comment: you can directly set values to domain, as for example `param.id` is boolean its default value will be false and so setting false to default value of `domain.id` is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through an object's properties like this:

```
Domain myMethod(DomainOld param) {

    Domain domain = new Domain()

    param.properties.each { property, value ->
        if (value) {
            domain[property] = value
        }
    }

    domain.save()

    return domain
}
```